Capacitance of multiple overlapping metal layers
Consider a set of metal plates arranged in a similar fashion to the picture below:

The capacitance between the layer labeled M5 and the layer labeled M4 can be calculated (ignoring fringe effects) as being $C_\mathrm{overlap}=\epsilon\frac{A_{\mathrm{overlap}}}{d}$ where I have defined $A_{\mathrm{overlap}}$ as the overlapping area of the two rectangles and $d$ as the distance between the layers. Imagine I place a charge $Q$ on M5 and a charge $-Q$ on M4. Is the voltage between the two layers simply $V=\frac{2Q}{C_\mathrm{overlap}}$? Or do I need to consider the other metal layers present and their potential voltage/charge distributions as well? For instance, I am wondering if a resistor $R$ is placed between M4 & M5, is the time constant simply $\tau=RC_{\mathrm{overlap}}$, or is it more complicated? And as a final question, is this a situation better suited for a simulation program to determine exact quantities such as $\tau$ (and are there any suggestions for which to use)?

Are these Mx metal strips isolated from each other only by an air gap of thickness d? Are the other than M4, M5 strips floating, connected to each other, grounded?

Let's assume they are separated by an air gap of distance d. Let's also assume they are floating with a charge Q' on them, where Q' != Q.

When the distance between the metal layers M4 and M5 is much smaller than the height of these layers and the lateral spacing of the stripes is not too large, then the parasitic capacitances between M5, M4 and the other layers are negligible compared to the overlap capacitances between the M5 and M4 stripes.
